# No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In my android app, there is an error while compiling the app. I am working in the latest android studio and using Firebase UI Auth and Firebase Database all the versions are in same in App level Grade file then why I am getting this error

ERROR:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.varunwadhwa.myapplication, PID: 12383
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.varunwadhwa.myapplication-G6TbLS-JLKb6r1uvHa6XnQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source:64)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source:14)
        at com.example.varunwadhwa.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Application terminated.
```

Build.gradle

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    //    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    //    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
```

Build.gradle Error
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.0, 27.0.2. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0 less... (⌘F1)
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

**build.gradle (project: my application)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url="com.google.maven"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle(module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.varunwadhwa.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    //    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    //    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.2'

}
```

Comment: Try upgrading the dependencies.

Comment: I have tried everything. I am trying to solve this problem from the past 2 days any help would be appreciated  @JawadAhmed

Comment: @vwadhwa3 did you try my answer?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes i did

Comment: @vwadhwa3 and did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After the `dependencies{}` in your build.gradle(module: app) file

Answer (score 0):

Just try re-adding all dependencies with lower versions that are being complained about, for example add

```
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
```

Sync and compile, if any shows up, add it too.
Let me know what happens.